# can i use two ng-repeat in inside td table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxsuc.png)
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc24D.png) 
Please guide me how to use two ng-repeat inside one td. when i use span tag after i am not getting expected result.i have use one ng-repat in td and other i have use in span tag so i am not getting expected result so how to use two ng-repeat in one td.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
         app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

           $scope.records = [
             {"year":2006,"quarters":{"q4":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2007,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":9.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2008,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2009,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2010,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2011,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":9.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2012,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":0.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":9.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2013,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":0.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2014,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":2.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2015,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":0.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2016,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":0.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2017,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":5.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2018,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":3.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2019,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":2.0,"fl":0.0},"q2":{"kk":4.0,"fl":0.0},"q3":{"kk":6.0,"fl":0.0},"q4":{"kk":7.0,"fl":0.0}}},{"year":2020,"quarters":{"q1":{"kk":8.0,"fl":0.0}}}
           ]
          
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Year</th>
      
       <td colspan="4" data-ng-repeat="years in records" ng-bind="years.year"></td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border:0">Question</td>
      <td style="border:0">&nbsp;</td>
     <td data-ng-repeat="years in records">
                  <span class="yearStyle text-center"  data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"
                              data-ng-init="asdasd()" ng-bind="key "></span>
      
    </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1">A205</td>
    <td>KK</td>
    <td data-ng-repeat="years in records"><input type="number" class="yearStyle  text-center" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"
                            ng-bind="value.kk" ng-model="value.kk"></td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td>FL</td>
   <td data-ng-repeat="years in records"><input type="number" class="yearStyle  text-center" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"
                            ng-bind="value.fl" ng-model="value.fl"></td>
   
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
   <td data-ng-repeat="years in records"><input type="number" class="yearStyle  text-center" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"
                            ng-bind="value.fl + value.kk" ng-model="value.fl + value.kk"></td>

  

  </table>
```

Comment: Please give me reply advance thanks for all my dear friends....

Comment: if you have any question regarding plz see two above link..

Comment: Please Guide me anyone ...

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply  plz check above link 
my current result Expected result

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your json data. You should have an **Array** of objects in years.quarters json property so that it can loop through in **data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in years.quarters"**
Currently, your years.quarters property is an **object**

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply...i will be do.